After upgrade to 24.04.1 LTS, why is login screen showing "23.10"?
All the other checks I've run on the release version show 24.04[.1] correctly.  It's not a huge issue, but it is one of the recommended ways for a user to find the version in use, and the display should not be false!

What are the output of the commands lsb-release -a and cat /etc/apt/sources.list?

This was an LTS upgrade - never downloaded 23.10.

This is the normal boot-up login screen (plymouth?).
Never changed the greeter or DM.

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
Ubuntu sources have moved to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
Types: deb
URIs: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
